# How can I concat a defined variable in oracle?

Tags: oracle, append

I'm new in Oracle db and I'm working on script. So I trying to run a lot of scripts with a relative
var path and I have subfolder.

```
Folder A:
  Folder A.Child-1
  Folder A.Child-2
  RunAll.sql

Folder A.Child-1:
  Script 1
  Script 2
```

I know we can define path var like:

```
define path='C:\Folder A.Child-1';
@&pathScr\RunAll.sql;
```

If I put a complete path for Eg: Script 1, the script can be exec. But is there any way to do something like:

```
define Scriptpath= Concat(&path, 'Folder A.Child-1')
@&Scriptpath\Script 1.sql;
```

So that I only need to declare the path only once.

**What I tried:**

```
define Scriptpath= concat(&path, 'Folder A.Child-1')
@&Scriptpath\Script 1.sql;


define Scriptpath= &path || 'Folder A.Child-1'
@&Scriptpath\Script 1.sql;

Declare Scriptpath:= = &path || 'Folder A.Child-1';
Begin
End;
@&Scriptpath\Script 1.sql;
```

All those trial return errors something like

```
Can not open file concat(&path, 'Folder A.Child-1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `concat`, just use the same way with simple variable substitution in shell scripting:

```sql
SQL> def path1='mypath'
SQL> def path2='&path1/xyz.sql'
SQL> prompt &path1
mypath
SQL> prompt &path2
mypath/xyz.sql
```